# Why selenium's click method is returning NoSuchElementException?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, scrapy

During scraping a javascript base website([link](https://portal.orio.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&productId=218044&catalogId=10051&categoryId=146003&errorViewName=ProductDisplayErrorView&urlLangId=-150&langId=-150&top_category=146001&parent_category_rn=146001&storeId=11901)), I've stuck with a click function which is not producing the desired result. I've pasted the code which should return the data under "Fits the following cars" drop down menu but unexpectedly it's just printing the except statement's message. I'm able to scrape all the other data from the same code. Should I add few more lines to get the data hidden under that drop down, if yes then what lines to add.

```
def product(self,response):
    while True:
        try:
            drop=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="toggleMakeModelArrow"]')
            self.logger.info('Sleep for 3 sec.')
            sleep(3)
            drop.click()
            sel=Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
            drop_down=sel.xpath('//*[@id="CachedItemDispaly_make_model_div"]/select/option/text()').extract()
            for i in range(len(drop_down)):
                print drop_down[i]+"||"

        except NoSuchElementException:
            self.logger.info('No more Fits the following cars to load..')
            break
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException" when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you keep receiving `NoSuchElementException` is that the dropdown is being inserted dynamically into `DOM` tree so you need to wait for some time until it is available. The best way to implement wait timeout is to use [wait API](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) provided by `python-selenium`.

Here is a working code where `time.sleep` being used as a temporary solution.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://portal.orio.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&productId=218044&catalogId=10051&categoryId=146003&errorViewName=ProductDisplayErrorView&urlLangId=-150&langId=-150&top_category=146001&parent_category_rn=146001&storeId=11901")

drop=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="toggleMakeModelArrow"]')

time.sleep(5)
drop.click()
time.sleep(5)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('orioVehicleMakeModeltypeInfo'))

for select_option in select.options:
    print(select_option.text)
```